# Java Spring boot - Issue using entities from Oracle Sql

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Using Intellij i've connected to an oracle database, added persistency framework and generated persistence mapping by database schema

```
package springoraclesql.demo.domain;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
private long bookId;
private String bookName;
private String bookAuthor;
private Long bookPrice;

@Id
@Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
public long getBookId() {
    return bookId;
}

public void setBookId(long bookId) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "BOOK_NAME")
public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
}

public void setBookName(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "BOOK_AUTHOR")
public String getBookAuthor() {
    return bookAuthor;
}

public void setBookAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "BOOK_PRICE")
public Long getBookPrice() {
    return bookPrice;
}

public void setBookPrice(Long bookPrice) {
    this.bookPrice = bookPrice;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Book book = (Book) o;

    if (bookId != book.bookId) return false;
    if (bookName != null ? !bookName.equals(book.bookName) : book.bookName != null) return false;
    if (bookAuthor != null ? !bookAuthor.equals(book.bookAuthor) : book.bookAuthor != null) return false;
    if (bookPrice != null ? !bookPrice.equals(book.bookPrice) : book.bookPrice != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int) (bookId ^ (bookId >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (bookName != null ? bookName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (bookAuthor != null ? bookAuthor.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (bookPrice != null ? bookPrice.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

I've added the Oracle jdbc and my `persistence.xml` under java/META-INF looks like this`

```
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <class>springoraclesql.demo.domain.Book</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My application.properties looks like this

```
oracle.dbsource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
oracle.dbsource.username=talon
oracle.dbsource.password=talon
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.name=talon
spring.datasource.password=talon
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

When I run the spring project I have many **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied** errors. But the url, username and passwords are correct.

```
2018-01-12 13:05:06.521 ERROR 10220 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
...
2018-01-12 13:05:06.536  WARN 10220 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
...
2018-01-12 13:05:06.568 ERROR 10220 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon d
...
2018-01-12 13:05:07.169 ERROR 10220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper   : Unable obtain JDBC Connection
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
...
2018-01-12 13:05:07.191  INFO 10220 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-01-12 13:05:07.438  INFO 10220 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice:    org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75f9eccc: startup date [Fri Jan 12 13:05:04 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-12 13:05:07.486 ERROR 10220 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Before I've tried connecting to the same schema using `DriverManager.getConnection` and I don't have any issue retrieving data that way.

Comment: Replace `oracle.` with `spring.` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, now I'm having `logon denied`, the url, username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was using spring.datasource.name instead of spring.datasource.username